# AWS AppSync subscribe to specific device/user for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I have implemented a sample Swift project related to AWS AppSync for real time data. 
Normally, it subscribes data to all iOS devices installing the App. 
But I want to subscribe the data to only specific device or user. 
Are there any good ways to do that ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use GraphQL **Arguments** with AppSync's subscriptions to subscribe to specific devices/users.

Here is the documentation for using subscription arguments:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-data.html#using-subscription-arguments